# Cannot access property of stdClass php

Tags: php

I am using a soap client in php to obtain information from a Soap service

I finally managed to get the call itself to work which is good news!

```
<?
$url = "MYURL";

$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); 
$SOAPCall = "Method";
$SoapCallParameters = new stdClass();
$SoapCallParameters->webUserKey = 'Value1';
$SoapCallParameters->urn = 'Value2';

$obj = $client->Method($SoapCallParameters);
var_dump ($obj);
echo $obj->{'LastName'};
?>
```

The method returns via Dump

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { [["LastName"]=> string(10) "Test"} ]}
```

However the echo statement does not print the LastName property

What am I doing wrong?  I have tried different combinations like putting the property into a string variable

I have tried other ways and its still not working

This method also does not work

```
$obj = $client->Method($SoapCallParameters);
$vars = get_object_vars($obj);
$arr = (array)$vars;

var_dump($arr);

$lastName = (string) $arr[0]["LastName"];
echo $lastName;
```

Doing a var_dump using the logic above gives

I can see from the var_dump that there are values in the response

```
array(2) {
  ["CheckRegistrationStatus_UrnResult"]=>
  string(10) "MatchFound"
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
    ["Age"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["FirstClaimClub"]=>
    string(47) "VALUE"
    ["FirstName"]=>
    string(6) "FIRSTNAME"
    ["LastName"]=>
    string(10) "LASTNAME"
    ["Registered"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["URN"]=>
    string(7) "VALUE"
  }
}
```

This now means that the way I am trying to reference last name is wrong

What is the correct syntax?

Paul

Comment: Is there an typo in your example? There seems to be an opening `[` but no closing

Comment: Hard to believe that's the actual var_dump output - that method does not tend to lie about the number of properties (`(2)`, but only one property named `LastName`?) or the length of strings (`string(10)` vs `"Test"`? Granted, non-printable characters can be an issue, but in that case you usually see at least one whitespace before or after the actual value. Check the source code view of this debug output, _not_ what your browser made of it when it interprets it as HTML.)

Comment: Sorry Dump is not lying I removed a load of other properties to simplify the question there is no issue with the service or the dump my question is why nothing is being extracted from the LastName property

Comment: I remember running into problems with this kind of stuff once. Try casting your value to string. I.e. `echo (string) $obj->LastName;`. Might work, cannot guarantee.

Comment: Nope that doesnt work

Comment: I have added another example that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_object_vars()`

```
$obj = $client->Method($SoapCallParameters);
$obj = get_object_vars($obj);
var_dump($obj['result']->LastName);
```

that will give you the idea.

Comment: This is just a different way of calling var_dump I am looking for getting to the value LastName and putting it into a variable

Comment: Now let me know what you are getting after var_dump this?

Comment: Please see main question - now it looks like the issue is with how do I get to the LastName property of the second element in the array which is where the result object is?

Comment: Exactly I know that, but if you will not provide output of my code, I will be unable to help you as I can create the data you are getting.

Comment: I added the output above I didnt want to put it in the comment as it is tidier in the main question

Comment: @Paul now check my answer. that should solve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example StdClass Object:

```
$obj = new stdClass();

$obj->foo = "bar";
```

Other example

```
echo $obj->foo; // -> "bar"
```

By variable's value:

```
$my_foo = 'foo';

echo $obj->{$my_foo};
```